# Spring Boot 2.0: Login attempt fails with default security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am currently struggling to setup a basic Spring Boot 2 application with default security (according to the [Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#security)).

My problem is that although i have not created a custom `WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` i can't login using the default form login (with the generated password), the login page just refreshes showing no indicator that the credentials were correct or incorrect. This is the page after the login attempt:

[image: Page after login attempt]

The `gradle.build` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE"
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

bootJar {
    baseName = "sample-service"
    version =  "0.0.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"

    // DevTools
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools"

    // Security
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
}
```

### Actions that did not solve this problem:

1. Configuring a custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which mimics the default security
2. Using `@EnableWebSecurity`
3. Explicitly define an `PasswordEncoder`

Do i miss some information about the default security introduced in Spring Boot 2.0?

### Update 1:

The `/error` page was protected by default security so a new `/login` page was shown (when redirected to the error page).
Skipping through the logs using debug log level (suggested by mohax) i found the the entry

```
2018-04-14 17:49:51.680 DEBUG 236 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
```

when receiving the login post request. This was quite odd due to no erros beeing shown while login. Ignoring the error page with the configurers `WebSecurity` results in a 403 Forbidden error beeing shown after an login attempt.

Comment: Try to add `@EnableWebSecurity` to `WebSecurityConfig` class

Comment: @mohax Tried it giving the same behaviour as above. But this should not be required when i'm not using a custom `WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter`.

Comment: And what in logs? May be you ned to explicitly define passwordEncoder?

Comment: @mohax There are no errors logged, the only logged info after application startup is related to the dispatcherServlet beeing initialized. Regarding the password encoder: Same behaviour, i will update my question to include this info. Btw. why would it be necessary to include a password encoder? The default security should provide a `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`.

Comment: Maybe you do not see some logs. Try to enable all logs in `application.properties` - `logging.level.root=DEBUG logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG`. Also you could try to add authmanager bean `@Bean
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }`

Comment: @mohax I've updated the question, the login post request results in an 403 Forbidden error, resulting in a redirect to `/error`. The error page seemed to be protected too so an empty login form is beeing shown. Why is the login post request forbidden? The default secururity should ensure this endpoint is not protected.

Comment: Please, show all project files. And also try to add `authorities` to users, defined in config

Comment: @mohax I have a Main class with annoted with `@SpringBootApplication` and one sample RestController, which are both not related to configuring spring security. My goal was to use the default security (with the default configured user with generated random password on startup), it should not be necessary to configure a user, or a password encoder, or a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to use the default form-/HTTP basic security. I will edit my question to include a link to the git repo.